# Forced Image download - file extension missing

Tags: javascript, http-headers

I got an AJAX function that loads a png from a canvas graph element and does (per user choice) open the image in a new browser window *or* force a download.

While the first works without a problem, I got a problem with adding the file extension to the download. Currently I simply get none, using the following HttpHeaders: `image/octet-stream`, `application/download(force-download, x-download)`

Gladly some SO user put a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/KkKXR/32/) together. <sup>1)</sup>

**Question**: How could I go and append a file extension (.png/.jpeg) to the forced download as seen in the JsFiddle example?

<sup>1) Sry, but I don´t know the User name anymore.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, with data uris, it is not possible to supply filenames. You should probably look at the HTML5 BlobBuilder API - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/27/creating-files-through-blobbuilder.aspx

Even with BlobBuilder, I've found that only Chrome acknowledges the filenames you supply, not Firefox.

Comment: How would you instead force a download?

Comment: There is no way to foce an image data uri. You will have to resort to BlobBuilder (simple example here: http://codebits.glennjones.net/downloadattr/downloadattr.htm), or use something like Downloadify (https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify).

Comment: Maybe zipping it up and then offering a download? Don´t want to rely on flash or a lib that´s  not supported by all browsers...

Comment: I´ll see. Maybe I could do it via `.htaccess` as it still uses Downloadify and therefore flash (no solution for ex. iphone).

Comment: Well, all these solutions are client side (Javascript). If you're going to use .htaccess, that's server side. In that case, there are a lot of options for you to generate and force a download upon the user. Do keep in mind that a .htaccess won't affect the data uri scheme you're currently using in your Javascript.